# How to refer correct worksheet in specific workbook when multiple workbooks are open?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub debug_tester()

    Dim A As Workbook
    Set A = Workbooks.Open("D:\a.xlsm")

    Dim B As Workbook
    Set B = Workbooks.Open("D:\b.xlsm")

    A.Sheets("sheet1_in_test").range("A1").Value = "test" 'pop out "subscript out of range" on this line

End Sub
```

And "sheet1_in_test" does exist in A. If I change it to number (i.e. sheet(1)) B is the one changed.

Edit: 
Correct the typos. Workbook A has one sheet named "sheet1_in_test". Workbook B has one sheet named "sheet1".

Edit:
Thanks **sancho.s**! It seems like `Workbook.Open` cannot refer the workbook when the sub located on it. Using `Set A = ThisWorkbook` seems work, too. I'm wondering why is that.

Comment: Your code says `"sheet1_in_test"`.  Your comment says `"sheet_in_test1"` exists.  Is this just a typo?

Comment: so `A.Sheets(1).range("A1").Value = "test"` will change `A1` in `B` ("D:\b.xlsm")?

Comment: what are the sheets present in workbook A and B respectively ?

Comment: Yes just typo, and yes if I run `A.sheets(1).range("A1").value = "test"`, it will change `A1` in the first sheet in workbook `B`

Comment: have a look at your drive "D". are the two files actual files? do "dir" command in a cmd window. are they shortcuts that someone switched around as a joke?  i think that there is a shortcut called "hard link" (or something like that) that may produce the issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: @jsotola - This is likely not possible. To open a workbook that is a shortcut one has to use the full name, i.e.,  `b.xlsx.lnk`.

Comment: Where is the `sub` located? Please locate it from an workbook other than the two you are opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sub`, located in a separate workbook, performs as intended

```
Sub open_test()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Documents\a.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user1\Documents\b.xlsx")    
    wb1.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").Value = "test"
    wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "test2"
End Sub
```

Try reproducing this.

Comment: That works! Seems like the `sub` will not refer the Workbook it located when using `Workbooks.Open`. Just wondering why is that?

Comment: @LeyKen - To answer that one should check exactly what you were doing; where was code located, and the sequence of operations you were carrying out. Probably not worth it at this point.

Answer (score -3):

Using Workbooks.Open() makes the opened workbook the active workbook. That's why using sheet(1) goes into workbook B. It's the last workbook opened and therefore the active workbook. Use Workbook.Activate to make A the active workbook.

```
Sub debug_tester()

    Dim A As Workbook
    Set A = Workbooks.Open("D:\a.xlsm")

    Dim B As Workbook
    Set B = Workbooks.Open("D:\b.xlsm")

    A.Activate
    A.Sheets("sheet1_in_test").range("A1").Value = "test" 

End Sub
```

If you still get the "subscript out of range" message, the "sheet1_in_test" worksheet is not in the A workbook. Check the spelling between the code and the worksheet name. This assumes that you are running the code from a 3rd workbook.

If you are running this code from workbook A, Excel will close the open instance of A and reopen it but the code won't be running. In that case you can use

```
Set A = ThisWorkbook
```

Or if the code is in workbook B use

```
Set B = ThisWorkbook
```

Comment: your comment would be correct only if the OA did not refer to the workbook, which the OA did do `A.sheets(1) ...`    is same as `Workbooks.("a.xlsm").sheets(1) ...`

Comment: I somehow messed up the previous post. Probably by fat fingering the keyboard. The latter part of the above changes were deleted. That first part was just to explain the Sheet(1) issue. Corrected.

Comment: The main point of your answer, using `Activate`, is bad advice. Fully qualifying objects (always using the workbook prefix) is way more robust than using `Activate`.

Comment: @Wolfie You're entitled to your opinion but in a debugging situation it is sometimes helpful, especially during maintenance, to clarify which workbook is selected. In this case it wouldn't matter because the code is in the a.xlsm workbook which causes the line Set A = Workbooks.Open("D:\a.xlsm") to reload the file so nothing after that line executes.